# Exec (cd and ls) and Fork call C

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, system-calls

I'm trying make a simple example with the exec() and fork(). But I have a little problem and I did't understand how fix it.

The code does 3 forks, and in each child it calls one exec. The first system call is "who", after "cd", and "ls -ls". My problem is: after made "cd", the "ls" call doesn't show the files in the current directory. So, if I have 'dir1/dir2', I do "cd", but when I do "ls" the program shows the files in 'dir/dir2'.

It's possible one child access the changes made by another child?

```c
while (cont_arg < 3) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("\n---: child process ID -> %d.\n", getpid());
            printf("command --- > %s\n", command[cont_arg]);
            execlp(command[cont_arg], command[cont_arg], arg[cont_arg], NULL);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            wait(&status);
        }
        cont_arg++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `execlp` to run the command `cd`, which is a shell builtin command, instead you should call `chdir` if you are on Linux, to change the current working directory of your process.

```
int chdir(const char *path);
```

Also check the return value of `execlp`:

```
int ret = execlp(command[cont_arg], command[cont_arg], arg[cont_arg], NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "exec failed for %s\n", command[cont_arg]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // will reach here only if exec failed
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the chdir and it worked.

Comment: one last question, when I use chdir, I will change the current directory to future children that I can create with the fork or just the directory of the current child?

Comment: @GabrielaCavalcante A child process created via fork(2) inherits its parent's current working directory. So yes, all children will have the changed one.

Answer (score 2):

> The first system call is "who"

No, those are not system calls. The term "system call" is used for something completely different. `who`and `ls` are programs that you execute with exec. `cd` on the other hand is a shell command. So executing `cd`, even if you did it correctly will not have any effect. Since `cd` just tells the shell process to change its internal state that is only visible to the shell and its child processes.

Unfortunately you don't see that exec of `cd` fails because you don't check for errors of `execlp`. Check the return value of exec and handle those errors and things will start becoming more clear.

Comment: Thanks! The teachers didn't explain very well about it, I will try find some book about this subject.